# Rounding number in table with siunitx

Tags: tables, siunitx

I want to round the number to 2 decimal places. I tried the below code, but it messes with the header.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \sisetup{round-mode=places}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{{|p{1.5cm}|c|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.6cm}|p{1.6cm}|}}
        \hline
        Molecule name & \# Structures & Mean $\Delta E$ (kcal/mol) & STD $\Delta E$ (kcal/mol) & Mean RMSD (\si{\angstrom}) & STD RMSD (\si{\angstrom}) \\
        \hline
        Propane & 10  & -5.532722 & 11.871219 & 0.525246 & 0.933334 \\
        \hline
        Pentane & 30  & -9.190216 & 2.529992 & 0.126386 & 0.047781 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{somcap}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Put the header texts between curly brackets `{...}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

Your`S` column settings as well table columns specifications are not complete. You need to specify `table-format` at each `S` column, move `round-precision` to `\sisetup` (for shorter column specifications), and define `\multicolumn` column header for fourth and fifth columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell}  % new, needed at column headers
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}{\multicolumn{#1}{c|}{\makecell{#2}}}


\begin{document}
                
\begin{table}
    \sisetup{round-mode=places,
             round-precision=2,
             table-column-width=3em % for equal 4 and 5 column widths
             }
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|p{1.5cm}|c
                    |S[table-format=-1.2]
                    |S[table-format=2.2]
                    |*{2}{S[table-format=1.2]|}
                    } 
        \hline
Molecule name
    & \# Structures
        & \mcc{Mean $\Delta E$\\ (kcal/mol)}
            & \mcc[2]{Mean\\ RMSD (\si{\angstrom})}
                & \mcc{STD\\ RMSD (\si{\angstrom})}     
                \\
        \hline
        Propane & 10  & -5.532722 & 11.871219 & 0.525246 & 0.933334 \\
        \hline
        Pentane & 30  & -9.190216 & 2.529992 & 0.126386 & 0.047781 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{somcap}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
Meanwhile OP change table design. For new style is needed to add new column header and remove option for two column cell. Since now are changed minimal column widths, it be finne to change it accordingly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array, makecell}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}{\multicolumn{#1}{c|}{\makecell{#2}}}


\begin{document}
                
\begin{table}
    \sisetup{round-mode=places,
             round-precision=2,
             table-column-width=4em
             }
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|m{1.5cm}|c
                    |S[table-format=-1.2]
                    |S[table-format=2.2]
                    |*{2}{S[table-format=1.2]|}
                    } 
        \hline
Molecule name
    & \# Structures
        & \mcc{Mean $\Delta E$\\ (kcal/mol)}
            & \mcc{STD\\ $\Delta E$ (\si{\angstrom})}
                & \mcc{Mean\\ RMSD (\si{\angstrom})}
                    & \mcc{STD\\ RMSD (\si{\angstrom})}
                \\
    \hline
Propane & 10  & -5.532722 & 11.871219 & 0.525246 & 0.933334 \\
    \hline
Pentane & 30  & -9.190216 & 2.529992 & 0.126386 & 0.047781 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{somcap}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have edited the question I don't have multi-columns. thnx for the help

Comment: @WhySoSerious, seriously? This change you can implement in my answer yourself ... it is simple ...

Comment: @WhySoSerious, see addendum to answer. Now you my consider to upvote it and accept it too (by clicking on check mark at top left side of answer; so far as I see, You not accept any answer from received on your questions).

Comment: I was trying to understand your answer to adding 1 column. I am new to latex.

Comment: can you please explain ```\mcc``` I am not able to understand how this multi-column new command works.

Comment: @WhySoSerious, the `\mcc` (abbreviation for  *multi column centered* )  is defined as shorthand for `\multicolumn{<number of columns>}{c|}{\makecell{<content>}}` . By it are overwritten co`S` column headers and enable to write multiline text. For definition is used command `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` originally defined in `xparse` package, now integrated in recent versions of LaTeX. How this command works is described in its documentation. It can find it on https://texdoc.org/serve/xparse/0